# saving 5 attachments and then retrieving them

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, phpmyadmin

I am asked to save the multiple attachments (a maximum of 5) to the database and then retrive them to another page in php.
I have googled for above a week for this, and find only tutorials which can save one file to database and then retrive them.

My scenario is i am sending an Email with those multiple attachments, Emails are saved in a table "Email" , Now i want the attachments also to be saved there, in another column, So it is easy to retrive them, on a php page.

Please any one help me in this case.
Provide me a proper guide line.
I m using phpmyadmin for saving all said things

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution you wanted:
Once you upload 5 files to the server read them into the memory and `base64_encode`.

E.g.

```
$files = array(
    'file1' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file1')),
    'file2' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file2')),
    'file3' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file3')),
    'file4' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file4')),
    'file5' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('/path/to/file5')),
);

// serialize
$filesData = serialize($files);    
// put $filesData in db column

// when your retrieve it later from database, unserialize and use array
$files = unserialize($columnValue);
```

Since you have files int memory and they are base64 encoded, you can add your attachments with `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64`.

Comment: When i unserialize the data, to get the files, it comes written there "Array". How can i get the actual files, in the form of a link to download anyone. Even in the database in the column where the files data is saved, i.e., [BLOB - 712.9KiB] , when i try to click on it, so see the files , a .bin type is saved. I have sent  .jpg files

Comment: @HanyaIdrees that's a different issue. If you want to display files as links you'll have to create a new page that takes some sort of file id (e.g. `download.php?email=xxx&fileId=xxx`, in there you will have to get the info from database + `unserialize` + `base64_decode` your desired file. Once you have all that display the file by setting the `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg')` or whatever file is and displaying file data `die($base64DecodedFile)`.

Comment: Can you please provide me a tutorial link, or any other helping link. I am a beginner in php, So Please

Comment: You can Google that , you know... [http://www.deadparrottavern.com/forum/showthread.php?10854-php-amp-mysql-uploading-files-into-a-database-and-pulling-them-out]